# Custom Google Sign-In Button in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui, google-signin

I'm having trouble using SwiftUI to make a custom Google Sign-in button. It will open a window allowing you that looks like it should allow you to login, but when I try to type anything into the text field, it won't type. Has anyone come across this? This is my app delegate (some of the print statements are just there rn for my reference):

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  WasteLESS
//
//  Created by Maya Reese on 5/26/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Maya Reese. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var user = UserData()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            self.user.authorized = true
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the function that hitting my "continue with google" button calls:

```
func GoogleButtonTapped(){
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

I'm a total beginner, so there might be stupid mistakes in there.

Comment: Better use UIViewController (by UIViewRepresentable) for social network login, so you can customize buttons and also SwiftUI view got some problems with GIDSignIn/facebook

Comment: Maya - have you tried using FirebaseUI? This is probably the easiest way to implement Google Sign-In for a Firebase app. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui#google) and the [sample project](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/samples/swift) on GitHub for how to use this in a Swift app.

Comment: instead of UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController, try UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController